# How to grouby data in one column and distribute it in another column in HiveSQL?

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

I have the following data:

| CompanyID | Department | No of People | Country |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 45390 | HR | 100 | UK |
| 45390 | Service | 250 | UK |
| 98712 | Service | 300 | US |
| 39284 | Admin | 142 | Norway |
| 85932 | Admin | 260 | Germany |

I wish to know how many people belong to the same department from different countries?

#### Required Output

| Department | No of People | Country |
| --- | --- | --- |
| HR | 100 | UK |
| Service | 250 | UK |
|  | 300 | US |
| Admin | 142 | Norway |
|  | 260 | Germany |

I was able to get the data but the Department was repeated by this query.

```
""" select Department, Country,count(Department) from dataset
    group by Country,Department
    order by Department """
```

How can I get the desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result set that you are producing is not really a relational result set.  Why?  Because rows depend on what is in the "previous" row.  And in a relational database, there is no such thing as a "previous" row.  This type of processing is often handled in the application layer.

Of course, SQL can do what you want.  You just need to be careful:

```
select (case when 1 = row_number() over (partition by Department order by Country) 
             then Department
        end) as Department,
       Country, count(*) as num_people,         
from dataset
group by Country,Department
order by Department, Country;
```

Note that the `order by` needs to match the window function clause to be sure that what `row_number()` considered to be the first row is really the first row in the result set.